# Updating a table in ms access with computed data from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've been working on an access project to manage a local high school football league...

So to record points  I created a table (results) with the following fields:

```
[result_ID, match_ID, team, points]
```

Now I'm trying to figure out a query that picks the sum of points per team from 1 table and updates them to another table from which I can now Derive the league leaders from, or

alternatively a query that sums up these points, per school, then from this I can create a report that shows the merit

Comment: how about Select sum(points) as totalPoints from yourTable group by Team?

Answer (score 0):

As an additional remark to the correct answer by krish KM (comment) I would recommend you go with a query instead of another table because as soon as new values are entered this other table becomes outdated and furthermore that table shows wrong data!

Comment: That's exactly what I did